# Prevent WPF controls from inheriting windowstyle

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How do I prevent my third-party controls from inheriting my main window style? The tool I'm using has its own windows that will not display correctly if I define a window style other than the default one.

```
<Window x:Class="myApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="myApp" Height="350" Width="525"
    WindowStyle="none" AllowsTransparency="True" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">
<Grid>
    <tool:thridPartyTool/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [InheritanceBehavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.inheritancebehavior.aspx) like this:

```
this.InheritanceBehavior = InheritanceBehavior.SkipAllNow;
```